# On boot, automatically assemble mdadm array that uses another mdadm array

Tags: raid, mdadm

I have two mdadm arrays on my system:

```
alex@fileserver:~$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md1 : active raid5 sdc1[0] md0[3] sde1[1]
      7759197184 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]

md0 : active raid0 sdd1[1] sdb1[0]
      3907019776 blocks super 1.2 512k chunks

unused devices: <none>
```

If you look real close, you'll see that `md1` uses `md0` in its array. (I had two 4 TB disks and two 2 TB disks, and this is how I wanted it working together...)

This works great, except on boot. Even though my `mdadm.conf` has these lines:

```
ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 UUID=ba271258:3f18f660:1d5d19aa:2bd0d8e3 name=fileserver:0
ARRAY /dev/md/1 metadata=1.2 UUID=262a6823:3fafb521:75e315ab:f2de4329 name=fileserver:1
```

it manages to assembly `md0` just fine, but `md1` is missing `md0` in its array, and ends up sitting there inactive, with only `sdc1` and `sde1` as spares. I'm guessing mdadm tries to assemble its arrays in parallel or something?

If, after boot, I do `mdadm --stop /dev/md1` and then `mdadm --assemble --scan`, the array is correctly put together.

My scenario is probably not very standard, but is there some simple solution to this issue? E.g. some way to tell mdadm.conf that `md1` depends on `md0`? I could always just write a small init script that does the stop/assemble commands for me after mdadm, but I'd rather avoid such hacks if a proper solution exists, especially since I have system services that rely on `md1` being present and mounted to work properly.

Comment: Not sure if these will help: use `/dev/md0` instead of `/dev/md/0`, remove `metadata=` `name=` (only UUID is enough), check UUID for typos, try to reverse line order, remember to update initramfs when changing `mdadm.conf`. If you don't mind completely reworking your setup, make two RAID5 of 2TB each. It should perform better and more reliably than md on md.

Comment: You can also specify `DEVICE` and for each array entry `devices=` but I doubt it would help, as long as you don't set these at all it should work. Can you show `dmesg` log of the boot process and failed assembly attempt?

Comment: There is probably not a simple solution for nested MDs. But there are standard solutions to make sure that your `mdadm` command is executed (if necessary) before those system services are started. Write a script which checks whether the RAID is already there and creates it if not, and call this script via a unit file (or SysV init script) on which those servies (i.e. their unit file or init script) depend on.

Comment: It could just be sheer luck, but I just upgraded my system from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 (yeah I know, I'm a little late...) and after the reboot for that, everything worked as it was supposed to. I'm reluctant to reboot again to test my luck, so for now, I'll just stick with this. But thanks, all of you, for your input and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Ubuntu bug that showed up in 12.04 (kernel ~3.2.0.40) and existed until fixed in 16.04. The same problem didn't appear in the Debian builds.

From conversation in the Ubuntu [bug tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mdadm/+bug/1171945):

> (user Tarantoga):
>
> It looks like [Debian] Wheezy disables udev for md and uses an rc-script for assembling at boot; therefore it will not automatically assemble arrays after boot.
> Trusty assembles real devices during and after boot, but seems to ignore virtual devices like /dev/md0.

Tarantoga found a simple solution by adding a single-line udev rules file:

`/etc/udev/rules.d/85-mdadm.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ACTION=="add|change", ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="linux_raid_member", DEVPATH=="*/virtual/*", RUN+="/sbin/mdadm --incremental $tempnode"
```

This solution just worked for me. I have a mirror of two stripes and only the stripes would assemble at boot time. Putting this rule in place caused everything to assemble properly.

(And, yes, I have a specific use case where a mirror of stripes is better than a stripe of mirrors :-)  )